# Adding data to a highchart chart using an array with IDs

Tags: javascript, highcharts, scatter-plot

I want to add a series to a highchart scatterplot where I am naming each point in the series. I create a chart in the following way:

```
var chart; // globally available

makeCharts = function(){

      chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
         chart: {
            renderTo: 'container1',
            type: 'scatter'
         },        
         series: [{
            name: 'a',
                data: [{                    
                    'id': 'point1',
                    'x': 1,
                    'y': 2
                }, {
                    'id': 'point2',
                    'x': 2,
                    'y': 5
                }]
            }]

      });
}
```

I would like to be able to update the points on the chart using something like:

```
chart.series[0].setData([{id:['point3', 'point4', 'point5'], y:[0,1,2], x:[1,2,3]}])
```

but this is not correct. Is it possible to update a chart using this approach where each point has an ID?

EDIT:

Just to clarify, I would like to be able to pass the arrays directly, rather than adding the data point by point using `addPoint()`. I could loop through an array and use `addPoint()` doing something like this:

```
id:['point3', 'point4', 'point5'];
y:[0,1,2];
x:[1,2,3];

for (i=0; i<x.length; i++)
  {
  chart.series[0].addPoint({
    x:  x[[i],
    y:  y[i],
    id: id[i]
});

  }
```

However, this is very slow. It's much quicker to add data using the following approach:

```
chart.series[0].setData([[1,0],[2,1],[3,2]]);
```

I have found that I can add data like this:

```
 chart.series[0].setData([[1,0, 'point3'],[2,1, 'point4'],[3,2, 'point5']]);
```

but then the only way that I can access the `id` when the point is selected, is through `this.point.config[2]`. With the following approach I am unable to use `chart.get('pointID')` to identify a point as I did not set the `ID`. I want to be able to identify the point using just the `ID`.

Comment: please update on the status of the problem, if any of the solutions helped mark accordingly, if there was something kindly consider leaving a comment at the least.

Comment: There is a function addSeries for this purpose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well broadly speaking there are two ways in which you can modify the chart data dynamically

1. [**Series.setData()**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.setData%28%29) Use this approach when you want to completely replace the existing data with some new data
2. [**Series.addPoint()**](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.addPoint%28%29) Use this approach when you want to add a subset of the points dynamically. This method is not just for adding one point at a time, if you read the documentation carefully again you will find that this method takes a boolean redraw argument, and the argument detail is as following

> **redraw**: Boolean
>   Defaults to true. Whether to redraw the chart after
>   the point is added. When adding more than one point, it is highly
>   recommended that the redraw option beset to false, and instead
>   chart.redraw() is explicitly called after the adding of points is
>   finished.

In your case, since you want to add a few points dynamically, but retaining the existing points, you should go with approach 2. But you need to use it inside a loop, with the redraw being set to false (hence solving the problem of being slow) and then after the loop, call the redraw method explicitly

**Code**

```
var id = ['point3', 'point4', 'point5'],
    y = [0, 1, 2],
    x = [1, 2, 3];

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    chart.series[0].addPoint({
        x: x[i],
        y: y[i],
        id: id[i]
    },false);
}
chart.redraw();
```

[Adding multiple points dynamically | Highcharts and Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/4Skzq/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [series.addPoint](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#object-Series).

```
chart.series[0].addPoint({
    x:  0,
    y:  0,
    id: 'anything'
});
```

But if you need to set data for series, use

```
chart.series[0].setData([{
    x:  0,
    y:  0,
    id: 'anything'
},{
    x:  2,
    y:  2,
    id: 'another'
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would like to be able to add an array in. I suppose I could use a loop with `addpoint()` to cycle through an array which would also work.

Comment: @celenius Can I take a look on the array which you want to add in?

Comment: I included it in my question above: `x=[1,2,3]; y=[0,1,2];id=['point3', 'point4', 'point5'];`

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you can pass your data like this:

```
chart.series[0].setData([[1,0, 'point3'],[2,1, 'point4'],[3,2, 'point5']]);
```

(as you stated in question), I can suggest you to use a little hack.

We'll need to add another statement to method `applyOptions` of Highcharts.Point prototype.

```
if (typeof options[0] === 'number' && options[2] && typeof options[2] === 'string') this.id = options[2];
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hEGbM/) you can see it in action.