# Elements not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, highcharts

I'm fairly new to JavaScript and I want to update elements in an array. I sort of took a stab at this code here.

```
var N = 2;
var Range = 64;
var array = [[0,100], [(Range),100]];
```

Variables ^^

```
$('#button2').click(function() {
  array.push([(Range/N),100]);
  array.sort();
  chart.series[0].setData(array);
  N=N+1;

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = [(((i+1)*Range)/N), 100];
    array.sort();
    chart.series[0].setData(array);
    i = i+1;
    alert(array);
  }

});
```

But for some reason, the elements don't update properly, I get this:

```
[10:33:48.782] [{x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}]

[10:33:50.053] [{x:48, y:100}, {x:48, y:100}, {x:48, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}]

[10:33:52.994] [{x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}]

[10:33:55.588] [{x:53.333333333333336, y:100}, {x:53.333333333333336, y:100}, {x:53.333333333333336, y:100}, {x:53.333333333333336, y:100}, {x:53.333333333333336, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}]

[10:33:57.721] [{x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}]

[10:33:59.298] [{x:56, y:100}, {x:56, y:100}, {x:56, y:100}, {x:56, y:100}, {x:56, y:100}, {x:56, y:100}, {x:56, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}]
```

What's happening?

Comment: Try to use `console.log` instead of `alert` and see the result in your console.

Comment: Why do you sort `array` at each step?

Comment: @raina77ow originally it was just an add element function but I decided to change the values of the elements as i added new ones and too lazy to remove the other array.sort() xD

Comment: `alert(var_dump(array));`  try this

Comment: [10:15:34.349] [{x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}, {x:64, y:100}] <-- this is my array afterward O.o

Comment: @Prashant, `var_dump` is not a javascript function

Comment: @Prashant that just ignores the respacing of the elements though

Answer (score 0):

try using this:**EDITED**

```
  var result = '';
for (var property in object) {// object is your array
  result += property + ': ' + object[property]+'; ';
}
alert(result);
```

for more detail visit here:[How can I display a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957537/how-can-i-print-a-javascript-object)

Comment: it is alerting which you where not getting.

Comment: because i have commented chart part.what is this chart.

Comment: Syntax from the Highcharts JS charting library

Comment: i have edited this you can use this as your array is giving [object object]

Comment: please read the edited question, i fixed the object object problem but thanks anyway :)

Comment: ok then you can see this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739926/adding-data-to-a-highchart-chart-using-an-array-with-ids. the problem is you are setting the data twice .

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

```
$('#button2').click(function() {
  array.push([(Range),100]);
  array.sort();
  N=N+1;

  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    newrange = i*Range/N;
array[i] = [newrange, 100];
  }
chart.series[0].setData(array);
console.log(array);
  });
```